# Laravel PayPal Integraton

Tags: payment-methods, paypal, laravel-framework

sorry for this post but I am struggling to find information about how to actually make a store front with the API and take payment with PayPal. A lot of the links seem to 404 or are outdated.
I have found a Laravel application (https://github.com/grayloon/magento-laravel-api) but I am struggling to find how the payment stuff actually works. I am not well versed in Magento as you can tell so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php

// Path: app/Http/Controllers/PaypalController.php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Srmklive\PayPal\Services\ExpressCheckout;

class PaypalController extends Controller
{
    public function getExpressCheckout($invoice_id)
    {
        $provider = new ExpressCheckout;

        $data = [];
        $data['items'] = [
            [
                'name' => 'Product 1',
                'price' => 9.99,
                'desc'  => 'Description for product 1',
                'qty' => 1
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Product 2',
                'price' => 4.99,
                'desc'  => 'Description for product 2',
                'qty' => 2
            ]
        ];

        $data['invoice_id'] = $invoice_id;
        $data['invoice_description'] = "Order #{$invoice_id} Invoice";
        $data['return_url'] = url('/paypal/ec-checkout-success');
        $data['cancel_url'] = url('/paypal/ec-checkout-cancel');

        $total = 0;
        foreach($data['items'] as $item) {
            $total += $item['price']*$item['qty'];
        }

        $data['total'] = $total;

        $response = $provider->setExpressCheckout($data);

        $response = $provider->setExpressCheckout($data, true);

        return redirect($response['paypal_link']);
    }

    public function getExpressCheckoutSuccess(Request $request)
    {
        $token = $request->get('token');
        $PayerID = $request->get('PayerID');

        $provider = new ExpressCheckout;

        $response = $provider->getExpressCheckoutDetails($token);

        if (in_array(strtoupper($response['ACK']), ['SUCCESS', 'SUCCESSWITHWARNING'])) {

            $invoice_id = $response['INVNUM'];

            // Perform transaction on PayPal

            $payment_status = $provider->doExpressCheckoutPayment($response['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT'], $token, $PayerID);

            if (in_array(strtoupper($payment_status['ACK']), ['SUCCESS', 'SUCCESSWITHWARNING'])) {

                // Perform transaction on website

                return redirect('/')->with('success', 'Payment success');
            }
        }

        return redirect('/')->with('warning', 'Payment failed');
    }

    public function getExpressCheckoutCancel()
    {
        return redirect('/')->with('warning', 'Payment failed');
    }
}
```

```php
<?php
// Path: app/Http/routes.php
use App\Http\Controllers\PaypalController;

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web', 'controller' => 'PaypalController'], function () {
    Route::get('/paypal/ec-checkout/{invoice_id}', 'getExpressCheckout')->name('paypal.express.checkout');
    Route::get('/paypal/ec-checkout-success', 'getExpressCheckoutSuccess')->name('paypal.express.checkout.success');
    Route::get('/paypal/ec-checkout-cancel', 'getExpressCheckoutCancel')->name('paypal.express.checkout.cancel');
});
```

```php
<?php
// Path: resources/views/welcome.blade.php
<a href="{{ route('paypal.express.checkout', ['invoice_id' => 1]) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Pay with PayPal</a>
```

```bash
// Path: .env
PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_USERNAME=YOUR_SAN
PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_PASSWORD=YOUR_SAN
PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_SECRET=YOUR_SAN
PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_CERTIFICATE=YOUR_SAN
PAYPAL_SANDBOX_APP_ID=YOUR_SAN

PAYPAL_LIVE_API_USERNAME=YOUR_LIVE
PAYPAL_LIVE_API_PASSWORD=YOUR_LIVE
```

```php
<?php
// Path: config/app.php
'providers' => [
    // ...
    Srmklive\PayPal\Providers\PayPalServiceProvider::class,
],

'aliases' => [
    // ...
    'PayPal' => Srmklive\PayPal\Facades\PayPal::class,
],
```

```php
<?php
// Path: config/paypal.php
return [

    'mode' => env('PAYPAL_MODE', 'sandbox'),

    'sandbox' => [
        'username' => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_PASSWORD'),
        'secret' => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_SECRET'),
        'certificate' => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_CERTIFICATE'),
        'app_id' => 'APP-80W284485P519543T'
    ],

    'live' => [
        'username' => env('PAYPAL_LIVE_API_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('PAYPAL_LIVE_API_PASSWORD'),
        'secret' => env('PAYPAL_LIVE_API_SECRET'),
        'certificate' => env('PAYPAL_LIVE_API_CERTIFICATE'),
        'app_id' => '',
    ],

    'payment_action' => 'Sale',

    'currency' => 'USD',

    'billing_type' => 'MerchantInitiatedBilling',

    'notify_url' => '',
    'locale' => '',
    'validate_ssl' => true,

];
```

```php
<?php
// Path: config/services.php
return [

    'paypal' => [
        'client_id' => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_USERNAME'),
        'secret' => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_SECRET'),
        'settings' => [
            'mode' => env('PAYPAL_MODE', 'sandbox'),
            'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 30,
            'log.LogEnabled' => true,
            'log.FileName' => storage_path() . '/logs/paypal.log',
            'log.LogLevel' => 'FINE'
        ]
    ],

];
```

```php
<?php
// Path: composer.json
{
    "require": {
        "srmklive/paypal": "^1.0"
    }
}
```

For detail: https://github.com/srmklive/laravel-paypal